# Redirect faster with Greasemonkey (or similar userscript engine)?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm using Greasemonkey to redirect certain URLs to another but I would like to redirect before the URL to be redirect loads.

Currently I'm using this simple script:

```
//==UserScript==
// @name Redirect Google
// @description Redirect Google to Yahoo!
// @include http://*.google.com/*
//==/UserScript==
window.location.replace("http://www.yahoo.com")
```

In the above, Google appears for a second and then redirected to Google. I want to go yahoo immediately. Is it possible, and how?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do something like this? I can think of many mean/malicious purposes, but seem to miss any practical reasons.

Comment: @F-3000 Just to provide an example of a practical application: I've been using a redirection script to redirect me from the standard version of Gmail to the old HTML version because it loads much quicker.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`@run-at document-start` in the metadata block<sup>Doc</sup>](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at).
EG:

```
//==UserScript==
// @name Redirect Google
// @description Redirect Google to Yahoo!
// @include http://*.google.com/*
// @run-at document-start
//==/UserScript==
window.location.replace ("http://www.yahoo.com")
```

The script will run before any document begins loading, thus before any scripts run or images load.

Comment: Yes, good answer. Note that this was not available at the time this question was originally asked, hence the not-as-good-answers, below.

Comment: Note that (at least on Firefox with tampermonkey) the redirection is made after the request is sent to the server, so it may still change some cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Greasemonkey is not the right tool for immediate redirects. (You are doing this for honest purposes, right?)

The easiest way, since you seem to have access to the victim's computer, is to change [**the hosts file**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file#Location_in_the_file_system).

(1) Add two entries/lines with these values (windows syntax):

```
74.6.117.48 google.com
74.6.117.48 www.google.com
```

(2) Restart the browser.  For IE, you may also need to flush the DNS cache (`ipconfig /flushdns` at the command prompt).

(3) Uninstall or disable that GM script.

(4) Google will now be redirected to Yahoo search.

Alternatively, you could write a browser extension/add-on.   But if this is for legitimate, non-prank use; the best, simplest, most flexible (and honest) approach is to leave the Greasemonkey script as is.

Comment: I want to redirect "abc.com" to "google.com" and "def.com" to "youtube.com". Go ahead, try to write a hosts file. Remember that both targets are on same CDN.

Comment: Not the most useful solution, since this requires admin rights, and affects EVERYTHING on the computer, not just browser. If done by IT-savvy person on less IT-savvy person's computer, may cause great confusion for the user, because address on browser points to google.com, yet page loads yahoo.com. Also, temporary turn-off would be more than just turning browser-addon off (one click for Greasemonkey, assuming you got the GM icon on browser's toolbar).

Comment: @F-3000, true, and I hinted as much in this, now outdated, answer (See [user873792's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10662143/331508).)  But typically when people do things like this, they want it to affect the whole computer.  Also, if it's for malicious purposes, it's **much** harder to affect the hosts file than to trick a victim into installing a dodgy userscript.  Note that the OP did not check any of the answers that would have worked if he had honest intentions and willing access to the target machines.

Answer (score 1):

The [Redirector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5064/) add-on for Firefox is what you should use for user defined redirects in Firefox instead of Greasemonkey.

Comment: Greasemonkey scripts are available for Google Chrome as well as Firefox, via the TamperMonkey extension. It would be better if it were possible to do this using Greasemonkey, due to its cross-browser portability.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this with [Userscripts for Safari](https://github.com/quoid/userscripts) using [the declarativeNetRequest API](https://github.com/quoid/userscripts/issues/184#issuecomment-1091038484).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Redirect Google
// @description Redirect Google to Yahoo!
// @run-at request
// ==/UserScript==

{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
        "type": "redirect",
        "redirect": {
            "transform": { "scheme": "https", "host": "www.yahoo.com" }
        }
    },
    "condition": { "urlFilter": "||google.com", "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"] }
}
```

You can also use a regex filter if preferred, e.g.:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Redirect Google
// @description Redirect Google to Yahoo!
// @run-at request
// ==/UserScript==

{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
        "type": "redirect",
        "redirect": {
            "transform": { "host": "www.yahoo.com" }
        }
    },
    "condition": { "regexFilter": "^https://www\\.google\\.com/example$", "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"] }
}
```

More info [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#redirects).

I haven't found a solution yet for Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey aside from [@user873792's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10662143) (which isn't as performant as the above example or using another add-on like Redirector for Firefox).