# Userscript to redirect when site is down

Tags: greasemonkey-4

I have script that redirects a website to an alternate website.

```
//==UserScript==
// @name Redirect Unreliable Site
// @description Redirect Unreliable Site
// @include http://*.[unreliablesite]
// @run-at document-start
//==/UserScript==
window.location.replace ("http://alternativesite")
```

[Redirect faster with Greasemonkey (or similar userscript engine)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506726/redirect-faster-with-greasemonkey-or-similar-userscript-engine)

It doesn't work if the original site is down. Is there a way to go to the alternate site without going to the original first?